# Apache Flink: How are events partitioned for a keyed CoFlatMapFunction?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

This is a pretty basic question about connected keyed stream.

If I have two streams with related events that share same logical key, and these streams are being connected (logically joined using the key) and this is all running with parallelism > 1, then how does Flink guarantee that two events from different streams with same logic key end up in the same parallel operator instance?

Here is a made-up example about hospital's patient streams - temperature stream and heartbeat stream. We want to join these two stream's by patient's id using `ConnectedStream` and `CoFlatMapFunction`.

```
DataStream<PatientTemperature> temperatureStream = ..
DataStream<HeartbeatStream> heartbeatStream = ..

temperatureStream
   .keyBy(pt -> pt.getPatientId())
   .connect (heartBeatStream.keyBy(hbt -> hbt.getPatientId() )
   .flatMap (new RichCoFlatMapFunction() {

         ValueState<PatientTemperatureAndHeartBeat> state = ...

         public void flatMap1(PatientTemperature value, Collector<PatientTemperatureAndHeartBeat> out) {
                state.value().setTemperature(value);  
         }

      public void flatMap2(PatentHeartbeat value, Collector<PatientTemperatureAndHeartBeat> out) {

               PatientTemperatureAndHeartBeat temperatureAndHeartBeat = state.value()
               temperatureAndHeartBeat.setHeartBeat(value)
               out.collect(temperatureAndHeartBeat);

      }

      });
```

Assume this is running with parallelism = 3, with operator tasks A, B, C, and they are all running in different physical machines.

Flink will guarantee that all `Temperature` events for patient "JohnDoe" will end up in the same parallel operator instance. Say it ends up in Operator B.

But when Flink receives `HeartBeat` events for "JohnDoe", how does it know to send them to Operator B where the patient's `Temperature` events were getting sent. Unless both `Temperature` and `HeartBeat` event are sent to the same parallel instance operator, the join would not work.

The fact that both streams are using the same logical key ( i.e patient's id) is application-specific and Flink does not know about. These two connected streams could be using their own keys which are unrelated to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the choice of the keys is application-specific. However, Flink is aware of how to access the keys since you are providing key-selector functions (`pt -> pt.getPatientId()` and `hbt -> hbt.getPatientId()`). Flink ensures that the keys of both streams have the same type and applies the same hash function on both streams to determine where to send the record.

Hence, the same values of both streams are shipped to the same operator instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would it still work if they had different keys - for instance, if one stream was keyed on patient ID (Integer) and another stream was keyed on patient's full name (String). Would Flink be able to send the same patient's record from both streams to the same operator instance?


temperatureStream
   .keyBy(pt -> pt.getPatientId())
   .connect (heartBeatStream.keyBy(hbt -> hbt.getPatientFullName() )
   .flatMap (new RichCoFlatMapFunction()

Comment: Flink checks that the types of the keys match. So an Integer key on one side and a String key on the other side would be rejected. Aside from that, Flink uses the keys that you specify.

Comment: @FabianHueske by "the same values of both streams are shipped to the same operator instance" you also mean the same physical machine right?

Comment: Yes, an operator instance runs on a single machine. But one machine can run multiple operator instances.